# Enable sourcemaps in Vue-Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bugsnag, vite

Is it possible to enable sourcemaps in Vue-Vite in production environment?

I would like to use it for Bugsnag.

Can't find anything about it in the docs.

[In dev it just works out of the box.](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/80)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Thanks to @tony19 I could find it out:

Since vue ~2.0 it works like this:

In `<projectRoot>/vite.config.js`:

```js
/**
* @type {import('vite').UserConfig}
*/
export default {
    plugins: [vue()],
    build: {
        sourcemap: true,
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank's . This is a good answer.

Answer (score 17):

Vite 2.x ([docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-sourcemap)):

```js
// vite.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
}
```

Vite 1.x:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default {
  sourcemap: true,
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I'm using `Vite 2.9` and a CSS sourcemap was not being loaded by the browser. (I'm also using Typescript, in case that is relevant to you.)

Based on the @types for `vite.config.ts`, there is a `devSourcemap` property under `css` which you can set to `true`.

Here is the `vite.config.ts` file I'm currently using:

```js
import ...;
...

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    checker({
      typescript: true,
      vueTsc: true,
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: Where is checker being defined?

Answer (score 9):

I use sass in my project and I add this to my vite.config.js, and got css sourcemap.

```js
        import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
        
        // https://vitejs.dev/config/
        export default defineConfig({
          css: {
            devSourcemap: true,
          },
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

This link will help you.

https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-sourcemap

This is a simple example for use:

// vite.config.js

```
 export default {
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
}
```